# What those Django documentation means by: "If DEBUG is set to False, all responses will be “Bad Request (400)”

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

**If DEBUG is set to False, all responses will be “Bad Request (400)”**

Do they mean this if Debug is set to false and you don't have a view template ?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/

**This is the context:** You normally won’t have to bother with writing 404 views. If you don’t set handler404, the built-in view django.views.defaults.page_not_found() is used by default. Optionally, you can create a 404.html template in the root of your template directory. The default 404 view will then use that template for all 404 errors when DEBUG is set to False (in your settings module). If you do create the template, add at least some dummy content like “Page not found”.

Warning
If DEBUG is set to False, all responses will be “Bad Request (400)” unless you specify the proper ALLOWED_HOSTS as well (something like ['localhost', '127.0.0.1'] for local development).
A couple more things to note about 404 views:

If DEBUG is set to True (in your settings module) then your 404 view will never be used (and thus the 404.html template will never be rendered) because the traceback will be displayed instead.
The 404 view is also called if Django doesn’t find a match after checking every regular expression in the URLconf.

Answer (score 2):

It means that If debug is set to true you'll only see the traceback for debugging.

If debug is set to false in order to render your 404 view you need to configure in **yoursite.settings**  the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting, as they say  ['localhost', '127.0.0.1'] in the case of local development. Of course in order to render a 404 you'll have to specify it in yourapp.views ...

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

example:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '.example.com', # Allow domain and subdomains
    '.example.com.', # Also allow FQDN and subdomains
]
```

or:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = '*'
```